# Geoserver ImageMosaicJDBC problem with interpolation setting

Tags: raster, geoserver, oracle-spatial, image-mosaic

I use the ImageMosaicJDBC plugin to connect to an Oracle raster table. Maybe someone can clarify some things about the interpolation settings. There are multiple location where I can define the interpolation which is confusing to me:

- **gdal_translate**
  gdal_translate -of georaster...
  co GENPYRAMID=BILINEAR ^
- **.xml file for ImageMosaicJDBC**
  scaleop  interpolation="1"
- **GeoServer Layer setting**
  Default interpolation setting=xx

The problem I have: I get a black/grey scaled border around my raster layer when I open it via WMS and I used the setting scaleop  interpolation="2" or "3" in my xml.

[image]

Btw. I don't understand how that .xml file of ImageMosaicJDBC works. Is it only accessed once when I create a new data store? Or is it accessed every time the layer is accessed?

Comment: I have the same problem with Geoserver 1.12 (since Geoserver 1.10). The border widens when I zoom in. From a certain zoom level, the whole picture is only filled with the border color.

Is there a fix for this issue?